Expo is not connecting to Android device
I'm trying to use expo go app to test my app on my Android device,
but when I run  npm start, I get following warnings and  app not loads to my phone after scanning the Qr code,
Networking has been disabled

Unable to reach well-known versions endpoint. Using local dependency map expo/bundledNativeModules.json for version validation

Dependency validation is unreliable in offline-mode

When I press W, the web version is working fine, But I can't use on my phone

Did you solve this?  I am facing the same issue - Expo no working on Android Emulator.

When creating a project, I used this command:
npx create-expo-app@latest.
Then, the solution is to use npx expo start instead of npm start.  It worked for me because npx pulls the latest framework dependencies.

I got that same error and it was fixed by running this:
npm install -g expo-cli

